# Aggregate tasks across different sites and display them in custom timeline

Tags: jquery

I would like to build a timeline where I can aggregate tasks which are located in different subsites. While I was searching around I found this [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151160/aggregate-task-list-using-rest-sharepoint-online) and I thought to use REST. But my biggest concern is how can I display them in a timeline? How can I construct the view so that it looks like the timeline is SharePoint?

Mind you, these are the requirements that I need the timeline to do:

- it should display a range of 15 weeks
- able to scroll forward in weeks and backward in weeks
- group the tasks together from each site

Thank you for your help.